# Putty Backspace key issue

Tags: putty

I am using putty for serial communication. Taking input from user and feeding it to my controller. I noticed that if user presses Backspace putty is not sending any code to controller it is just clearing text on screen. But if I press Enter Putty properly sending it's corresponding code to controller. Is there any way I can enable Putty to send the Backspace code to send to controller at the same time it clears the text on the GUI?

Comment: How did you check it's not being send? What options did you try to change the behavior? Did you try any of the key board configuration options to see if that changes the behavior?

Comment: I checked the received value by comparison. When I pressed Enter key and compared it with 13 comparison become true, but for Backspace when I compared it with 8 the comparison fails. However I get interrupt for character reception, I did not check for Backspace if I got any interrupt. I need to check it.